# Animate lightcircles using shader

Tags: animation, shaders

I'm messing with a texture coordinate or object mapping to get a bunch of circles (in a single object) to light up from the inside to the outside..I've messed with all kinds of parameters but frankly I don't know what I'm really doing.

How can I manipulate the coordinates or the mapping so the light starts with the inner circle and grows to the outside?

[image]

Edit:

I fixed it using Christopher's solution, the UV method of moonboots didn't work as my object/UVmapping were different.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, and what happens once the light has filled the circles?

Comment: that's the last keyframe, I'll just add a cycler to repeat after that

Comment: Use _Object_ Texture Coordinates, and put a Gradient Texture set to "Spherical" before your ColorRamp. You may or may not need to also use a math node (or manipulate your mapping _scale_ to make the gradient encompass the whole object).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that your UV is not the same, it doesn't change anything, you just need to scale some vertices in the UV Editor to make it work

Comment: @moonboots I tried it in a new blendfile from scratch and it works now..can you elaborate a bit on how it works with the -0.5 location? Also, with an emission strength of 20, it seems the emission stength is lowered with the colorramp selection?

Comment: because by default the center of the gradient will be at the 0:0 position in the UV Editor which is the bottom left corner, so you need to place it at the center of the UV Editor instead, which is 0.5:0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unwrap your circular object with the *Project from View* mode, thin the UV islands if you want the light to appear with no transition:

[image]

Choose the *Texture Coordinate UV* output, in the *Mapping* node set *Location* X and Y to -0.5, plug into a *Gradient* node / *Spherical* mode, move the blue needle of the *ColorRamp* from right to left:

[image]